# Payflow gateway and Payment Advanced

Tags: paypal, credit-card, payflowpro

I want to test PayPal Payment Advanced on my site an use this:https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929/. Now I finished intergrating it with  my site. But now I can pay with PayPal Account, I failed to get payment with a Credit Card, I can't get any wrong response from PayPal when I use this API. This is my Code:

```
 public NameValueCollection PayAdvanced(VM_BasketOrder basketOrder)
        {
            string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority;
            string ReturnURL = baseUrl + Url.Action("ReturnPayAdvanced", "ShoppingCart");

            string CancelURL = baseUrl + Url.Action("CancelPay", "ShoppingCart");

            StoredAddress billAddress = basketOrder.billto_sAddress;
            StoredAddress shipAddress = basketOrder.shipto_sAddress;

            NameValueCollection requestArray = new NameValueCollection()
            {
                {"PARTNER", "PayPal"},  

                {"VENDOR", "s04124226"},  
                {"USER", "g041234226"},
                {"PWD", "k_123452346789"},


                {"CREATESECURETOKEN", "Y"},
                {"SECURETOKENID", genId()},

                {"TRXTYPE", "S"},//A
                {"SHIPAMOUNT", basketOrder.ShippingAmount.ToString()},
                {"AMT", basketOrder.Total.ToString()},
                {"TAX", basketOrder.SalesTax.ToString()},
               // {"ACCT","4111111111111111"},
               // {"EXPDATE","1215"},

                {"CURRENCY", "USD"},

                //{"SILENTTRAN","TRUE"},

                {"RETURNURL", ReturnURL}, 
                {"CANCELURL", CancelURL},
                {"ERRORURL", CancelURL},

                {"BILLTOFIRSTNAME",billAddress.Name.AddressNameSplit()[0]},
                {"BILLTOLASTNAME", billAddress.Name.AddressNameSplit()[1]},
                {"BILLTOSTREET", billAddress.Street1},
                {"BILLTOCITY",billAddress.City},
                {"BILLTOSTATE",billAddress.State},
                {"BILLTOZIP",billAddress.Zip},
                {"BILLTOCOUNTRY",billAddress.Country},

                {"BILLTOPHONE","55555"},


                {"SHIPTOFIRSTNAME", shipAddress.Name.AddressNameSplit()[0]},
                {"SHIPTOLASTNAME", shipAddress.Name.AddressNameSplit()[1]},
                {"SHIPTOSTREET", shipAddress.Street1},
                {"SHIPTOCITY", shipAddress.City},
                {"SHIPTOSTATE", shipAddress.State},
                {"SHIPTOZIP",shipAddress.Zip},
                {"SHIPTOCOUNTRY",shipAddress.Country},

                {"SHIPTOPHONE","55555"},
            };

            NameValueCollection resp = run_payflow_call(requestArray);


            return resp;
        }

        protected NameValueCollection run_payflow_call(NameValueCollection requestArray)
        {
            #region send request to Payflow
                String nvpstring = "";
                foreach (string key in requestArray)
                {
                    //format:  "PARAMETERNAME[lengthofvalue]=VALUE&".  Never URL encode.
                    var val = requestArray[key];
                    nvpstring += key + "[ " + val.Length + "]=" + val + "&";
                }

                string urlEndpoint = "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/";

                HttpWebRequest payReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlEndpoint);
                payReq.Method = "POST";
                payReq.ContentLength = nvpstring.Length;
                payReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(payReq.GetRequestStream());
                sw.Write(nvpstring);
                sw.Close();
            #endregion

            #region get Payflow response
                HttpWebResponse payResp = (HttpWebResponse)payReq.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(payResp.GetResponseStream());
                string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            #endregion

            #region parse string into array and return
                    NameValueCollection dict = new NameValueCollection();
                    foreach (string nvp in response.Split('&'))
                    {
                        string[] keys = nvp.Split('=');
                        dict.Add(keys[0], keys[1]);
                    }
                    return dict;
            #endregion

        }

        protected string genId()
        {
            var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            var random = new Random();
            var result = new string(
                Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 16)
                          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                          .ToArray());
            return "MySecTokenID-" + result; //add a prefix to avoid confusion with the "SECURETOKEN"
        }
```

I use this code, and I get passed a tokenid and token to next code.

```
  <iframe src="@("https://payflowlink.paypal.com?MODE=TEST&SECURETOKENID="+ViewBag.SECURETOKENID+"&SECURETOKEN="+ViewBag.SECURETOKEN)" name="test_iframe" scrolling="no" style=" width:480px;height:490px;border:0px;"></iframe>
```

I get the PayPal iframe on my site, click the PayPal button, I can pay successfully, but when I enter a credit card number and click "pay now", I can't get money in my test account. Now I don't know how to debug my code, because it is executiin in PayPal, so I can't find where the mistake is in my code. So I pasted my code here, and hope some can help me.

**today I find, when I use credit card pay, PNREF=V72A4DR7AE07, I can't get PPREF. when I use PayPal Account to pay, I can get PNREF and PPREF all. And PPREF is the PayPal transactionId.**

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you are saying is happening.  Are you trying to test and you dont have an option to pay with a credit card, or your transactions are going through but you are trying to generate a failure.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: i edited my question.please see again,i hope you can understand me and help me.thank you.

Comment: What specifically happens?  Is there any error message?  Can you provide a link to your checkout to walk through it and see what its doing?

Comment: thank you for response me. today i find after pay with credit card,i get response from paypal.RESULT=0,RESPMSG=Approved,and i get the TransactionId,everything is ok,but i can't get money,i don't know why.

Comment: today i find, when i use credit card pay,PNREF=V72A4DR7AE07,i can't get PPREF. when i use PayPal Account to pay,i can get PNREF and PPREF all. And PPREF is the paypal transactionId.